# Number of Objects (3) not equal to number of keys(8)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Ok, so the issue is coming from trying to pull data from a sqlite DB and place it in an array for a scroll view display. Im using FM Database library to connect to sql database

The code is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
FMResultSet *result = [[[StorageTank sharedStorageTank] DB] 
                                        executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM table"];
while([result next])
{
    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
                     [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[result intForColumn:@"id"]],
                     [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[result intForColumn:@"count"]],
                     [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[result intForColumn:@"required"]],
                     [result stringForColumn:@"image_portrait"],
                     [result stringForColumn:@"image_landscape"],
                     [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[result intForColumn:@"end_date"]],
                     [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:[result intForColumn:@"active"]],
                     [result stringForColumn:@"merchant"], nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", values);

    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"id",@"count",@"required",
                     @"image_portrait",@"image_landscape",
                     @"end_date",@"active",@"merchant",nil];
     NSLog(@"%@", keys);

    NSDictionary *row = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: values  forKeys: keys];


    [data addObject: row];
}

NSArray *resultArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
resultArray = data;
```

So, obviously from the code i've tested to make sure the values count is equal to the keys count... yet Im still getting this error:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: number of objects (3) not equal to number of keys (8)'"

I can't understand for the life of me why the count would differ if when I print out the values array I see 8 values... which should match my 8 keys? and they are correct?

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that possible I'm running into a memory issue as the image_portrait/image_landscape are base64 encoded image strings?

Comment: What does the log statement for values show? Any chance you are getting nil values for the NSNumber values?

Comment: Note that that code leaks like a sieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the fourth item in your values array:

```
[result stringForColumn:@"image_portrait"]
```

returning `nil`?  That's the value that tells -initWithObjects that the list is done.

Comment: Yep... it was... wow. Thank you, for pointing out the obvious. Its been a pain for the past 2 days...